# How to translate the construction "noun + で"

Tags: nouns, copula

When going over a summary of Japanese grammar I came across the following sentence:

> 私は学生で友だちはいしゃです。

How should this be translated? It supposedly covers the construct of noun+で. Is it the te-form?

Answer (score 4):

”で” Here is the te-form of the coupla "だ/です" and means simply "is", but it has the connotation of continuing on with the sentence, instead of ending it like "だ" would.

So "AはBで。。。" would mean "A is B and..."

Answer (score 3):

Both nouns(**名詞**) and na-adjectives(**形容動詞**) have the same continuative-form(**連用形**) which is the form you use in a sentence to keep it going, and consist in appending **で** to them at the end.

> - [彼女]{かのじょ}　は　**[静]{しず}かで**　**18[歳]{さい}で**　[美人]{びじん}です 。
> - She's quiet, 18 years old and a beauty.

In the example above we chained a na-adjectve followed by a noun(years) – also chained – and finished with another adjective.