# the meaning of で in 私は学生で友だちはいしゃです。

Tags: copula

Can anyone tell what で means in this sentence: 私は学生で友だちはいしゃです。Thank you. It looks like the で in this sentence means "and" but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24917/5010

Comment: 同じ文が質問されてました：https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36264/9831

Comment: It means "and by the way"

Answer (score -1):

You are right, it means "and".

That is the te-form of the copula だ.
According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 466:
"The te-form functions, in part, to link sentences"

Examples:
ジムは日本へ行って、勉強した。
Jim went to Japan and studied.

このステーキは安くて、美味しい。
This steak is cheap and delicious.

このアパートは静かでいい。
This apartment is quiet and good.

父は先生で、英語を教えている。
My father is a teacher, and teaches English.

Comment: どこからどこまでが引用かわかりません。　例文と英訳は引用ではないのですか？　引用された箇所がどこなのかわかるように示してください。